# best practice for multiple return type from function

Tags: python, return, return-value, return-type

I just start with python and get one question. is it a good idea to design a function return multi type of value? I read some information on sit and totally understand it is better to rise exception when an error is encountered or a precondition is unsatisfied. but what if there is no error but just different multi type of return value? it is a dummy function but for multi_value function, i do not need to write something like **multi_value()[0]** if I need to access the value from function
refer:https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/returning_more_than_one_variable_type_from_function_call.html

```
from typing import Union
def multi_value(para : Union[list, int]):
    return para[0] if len(para) == 1 else para

def fun(para : Union[list, int]):
    return para

print(type(multi_value([1,2,3]))) #--> [1,2,3]
print(type(multi_value(['1']))) #--> '1'
print(type(multi_value([1]))) #--> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of not having different types is to make your functions easier to use. If the caller has to check the return type he gets unnecessarily complicated, hard to read and error prone code. Even worse: the caller might not do the check at all and then gets caught by surprise. You show a nice example: returning a list or a scalar value. If you do as shown the caller has to write something like

```
res = multi_value(x)
try:
    for i in res:
        do_something_with_res(i)
except TypeError:
    do_something_with_res(res)
```

Given your function really does not throw anything this all would collapse to

```
for i in multi_value(x)
    do_something_with_res(i)
```

if you would returning single (or no) values also as lists. The advantage should be obvious. You may think you do the caller a favor - but that is just not true.

Some remark to the linked article: I think they gave a sub-optimal example on the matter. The example is more about returning error code vs raising exceptions, which is a little different.